# Javascript : How can I enter a '@' in an url?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a code which let me change a value in an another page using a form submit in Javascript, the problem is that the url does not accept the value **@** (*@ = %40* in the url)

***here is the code:***

**index.html**

```
<form method="GET" action="page.html">
  <input type="text" id="my_text" name="my_text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**page.html**

```
<input id="title"></input>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, 
          function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }
  document.getElementById("title").value = getUrlVars()["my_text"];
</script>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is this IIS, Apache? What is routing this request?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Comment: Do you see the %40 in the url when the page is submitted?

Comment: What is `console.log(window.location.href);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I had to use decodeURIComponent(), which let me get the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `encodeURI()`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent/3608791#3608791) for an in depth explanation.

Comment: Use it where in the code? The browser does it be default with the form submission...

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it isn't encodeURI() but it helped me to find decodeURIComponent() which works fine!